# How to select product that have the same range price for particular month?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has items:

```
ProductId  Month  range_prc   Price   Region
   1001      1      101         88      10
   1002      1      100         44      10
   1003      1      100         34      20
   1001      2       88         88      10
   1002      2      100         54      10
   1003      2      100         34      20
   1001      3      100         33      10
   1002      3      100         23      10
   1003      3      100         13      20
   1001      4      102         56      20
```

How to select priductId that has range_prc=100 from month 1-3

this is what i have tried so far:

```
    select productId, region, 
    sum(if(mothn =1, range_pr, 0))  AS Jan, sum(if(month = 2, range_pr, 0))  AS feb, 
    sum(if(month= 3, range_pr, 0))  AS Mar
    from table
    where range_pr=100 
group by productId, region
```

and the result is:

```
ProductId    Region  Jan  Feb   Mar
   1001       10      0    0    100
   1002       10     100  100   100
   1003       20     100  100   100
```

but i want to display only product that have same range_prc in three periods like this:

```
ProductId    Region  Jan  Feb   Mar
  1002       10     100  100   100
  1003       20     100  100   100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HAVING`:

```
select productId, region, 
       sum(if(month=1, range_pr, 0)) AS Jan,
       sum(if(month=2, range_pr, 0)) AS Feb, 
       sum(if(month=3, range_pr, 0)) AS Mar
from table
group by productId, region
having Jan = 100 AND Feb = 100 AND Mar = 100;
```

Or you can use a subquery:

```
select *
from (
  select productId, region, 
         sum(if(month=1, range_pr, 0)) AS Jan,
         sum(if(month=2, range_pr, 0)) AS Feb, 
         sum(if(month=3, range_pr, 0)) AS Mar
  from table
  group by productId, region
  ) p
WHERE Jan = 100 AND Feb = 100 AND Mar = 100;
```

Comment: I think you can use your aliases in the `HAVING`.

Comment: @shmosel I just tested the aliases in `HAVING` and they work, cool :) I'll update the answer

Comment: it's work, thank you so much @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister

Comment: @Wirjoe whenever you like an answer or a comment, praise it by voting it up rather than with another comment ;)

Comment: This relies on knowing in advance what the price is. I can't see how that's useful, but I'm pleased the OP disagrees. Still, `Jan = Feb = Mar` would seem like a more useful condition.